# Return duplicates in a list based on 2 criteria

Tags: r, list, duplicates, subset

I have a list that contains 2 data sets.

```
a = data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), c("a","b", "c", "d","e","e","f", "g", "h","i"))
colnames(a) = c("Numbers","Letters")
c = data.frame(c(3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), c("q","r", "s", "t","u","u","v", "w", "x","y"))
colnames(c) = c("Numbers","Letters")
my.list = list(a,c)
my.list
```

I am interest in returning only the letters that are found in common between the unique numbers of each data set. The desired results are given by the following:

```
new_a = data.frame(c(1,2),c("e","e"))
new_c = data.frame(c(3,4),c("u","u"))
colnames(new_a) = c("Numbers","Letters")
colnames(new_c) = c("Numbers","Letters")
my.new.list = list(new_a,new_c)
my.new.list
```

As you will see, letter "e" is the only common letter that numbers "1" and "2" share in data set 1 while letter "u" is the only common letter shared by numbers 3 and 4 in data set 2.

I am trying to do this for a very large list. To give you an idea of my true problem, I have a list where each element is a state. Within each state, I have multiple asset managers or "accounts" and each account holds multiple tickers. I am trying to find the tickers that the accounts have in common for each geographical locations. In the above example, the numbers would be the accounts, the letters would be the tickers and the two data sets contained in the list would be two different states. I hope that helps frame my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: `c` is a very commonly used function, so you might not want to use it as the name of something else.

Comment: I have a doubt with your description.  Suppose if the dataset is extended to include one more category of 'Numbers' i.e.  `a1 <- rbind(a, a[1:5,]); a1$Numbers[11:15] <- 3; a1$Letters[15] <- 'f'` What would be the expected result based on the new dataset `a1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `intersect` in `base R`

```
 lapply(my.list, function(x) x[with(x, Letters %in%
                 Reduce(intersect, split(Letters, Numbers))),])
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 lapply(my.list, function(x)
                    x %>% 
                        group_by(Letters) %>% 
                        filter(n_distinct(Numbers)==2))
```

Instead of having a `list`, it can be changed to a single dataset with an additional grouping column and then do the same,

```
 library(tidyr)
 unnest(my.list, group) %>%
            group_by(group, Letters) %>%
            filter(n_distinct(Numbers)==2)
```

If we don't know the number of unique Numbers in each list elements

```
  unnest(my.list, group) %>% 
              group_by(group) %>% 
              mutate(n= n_distinct(Numbers)) %>%
              group_by(Letters, add=TRUE) %>% 
              filter(n_distinct(Numbers)==n) %>%
              select(-n)
```

Comment: The first piece of code worked to perfection! Absolutely brilliant.

Comment: @thatcher1986 Glad to know that it works.  Could you clear the confusion as I stated in the comments

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
a <- as.data.table(a)
a[, if(.N > 1) .SD, by = list(Letters)]
#    Letters Numbers
# 1:       e       1
# 2:       e       2
```

Explanation: Take table `a` and group by the column `Letters` (`by = list(Letters)`) and return the subset of data for each group (`.SD`) only when the number of rows (`.N`) for *that* group is >1.

Comment: Based on the wording from the OP, this would fail in certain situations.  Also, this is not considering the `my.list`

Comment: the square bracket has some overhead, so I'd do `if (.N>1) .SD` instead of `.SD[.N>1]`

Comment: I guess the OP knows how to extend this to a list, but it's: `lapply(my.list,function(x)as.data.table(x)[,if(.N>1).SD,by=Letters])`

Comment: @Frank That is not the only issue.  The OP wants only the common elements, wouldn't this also include elements that are not common in all the Numbers, say if there are more categories of Numbers

Comment: @akrun Maybe you can add a small example to illustrate how your answer covers the case you're talking about? I don't really follow; this answer matches my reading of the question.

Comment: @Frank This is the description `I am interest in returning only the letters that are found in common between the unique numbers of each data set.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78575/discussion-between-frank-and-akrun).